# Using Nuget with redistributable source codes

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

We sell source codes for some of our apps and try to keep dependencies to a minimum. Currently, when customer gets the source codes, he can open a solution and start coding right away, the only prerequisite is to have VS 2010 or more.

We considering using Nuget. Is it safe to manage project dependencies with Nuget even if most of our customers don't have it installed?

I can see that Nuget saves all needed libraries in the "packages" folder and adds references to them, so it appears pretty safe to me. I've done some testing: uninstalled Nuget and tried to build the project, all worked fine, but I only have VS2012.

I couldn't find any accurate info on this topic nether in official documentation, no on other web-sites. So, does anyone know for sure, is it required to have Nuget installed in Visual Studio to work with nuget-enabled projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is your intention to redistribute those packages as binaries bundled with your sources, then NuGet is not required.  However, if you don't plan to redistribute those packages, then the customer must have NuGet installed.

<opinion>
I don't think it's unreasonable to make NuGet a requirement for the use of your sources.  It's easily installed into VS2010 and present by default in VS2012.  Microsoft is increasingly relying on it as a core part of the tool chain.  Resistance is futile. :) </opinion>